# Trying to play multiple video files simultaneously in Gstreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer

Im trying to make a command for gstreamer so it can play multiple video files simultaneously. So I done some research and found this one

```
gst-launch -e videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink \
    videotestsrc pattern=1 ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, width=320, height=180 ! \
    videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix. \
    videotestsrc pattern=15 ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, width=320, height=180 ! \
    videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=-320 ! mix. \
    videotestsrc pattern=13 ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, width=320, height=180 ! \
    videobox border-alpha=0 top=-180 left=0 ! mix. \
    videotestsrc pattern=0 ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, width=320, height=180 ! \
    videobox border-alpha=0 top=-180 left=-320 ! mix. \
    videotestsrc pattern=3 ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, width=640, height=360 ! mix.
```

This is the output image= https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lZWL.png

and here is the code that i modified that suppose to be like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdsc0.png

```
time gst-launch -e videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink \
    filesrc location=./Cityscape1Min_720p_mp4.mp4 ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, \
        width=320, height=180 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix. \
    filesrc location=./Cityscape1Min_720p_mp4.mp4 ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, \
        width=320, height=180 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=-320 ! mix. \
    filesrc location=./Cityscape1Min_720p_mp4.mp4 ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, \
        width=320, height=180 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-180 left=0 ! mix. \
    filesrc location=./Cityscape1Min_720p_mp4.mp4 ! video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, \
        width=320, height=180 ! videobox border-alpha=0 top=-180 left=-320 ! mix.
```

But it does not work. Anyone have other solutions?

Comment: guess you need to decode your video files. try to insert `decodebin2 ! videorate !` before each `videobox` element.

Comment: still cannot. error said Stream contain no data

Comment: 'Stream contain no data' ? Are you sure that you can play back the file by itself with a pipeline that does not have videomixer?

Comment: @maxtaldykin I have made the change however when I run the pipeline, it gives me no output, just this message: `Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...` `Pipeline is PREROLLING ...` and hangs after that.

Comment: @Dejan, maybe you need to put `queue` before `videobox`. It's hard to say without seeing your actual pipeline.

Answer (score 5):

I like this approach, it will create a matrix of 2x2. sink_0 is your background, you can also set it as an image. More info on [picture in picture](http://www.oz9aec.net/index.php/gstreamer/347-more-gstreamer-tips-picture-in-picture-compositing).

```
gst-launch -e \
videomixer name=mix \
        sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0  sink_0::alpha=0\
        sink_1::xpos=0   sink_1::ypos=0 \
        sink_2::xpos=200 sink_2::ypos=0 \
        sink_3::xpos=0   sink_3::ypos=100 \
        sink_4::xpos=200 sink_4::ypos=100 \
    ! xvimagesink \
videotestsrc pattern="black" \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=400,height=200 \
    ! mix.sink_0 \
uridecodebin uri='file:///home/user/video/test1.mp4' \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=200,height=100 \
    ! mix.sink_1 \
uridecodebin uri='file:///home/user/video/test2.mp4' \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=200,height=100 \
    ! mix.sink_2 \
uridecodebin uri='file:///home/user/video/test.avi' \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=200,height=100 \
    ! mix.sink_3 \
uridecodebin uri='mms://server/video/test.wmv' \
    ! ffmpegcolorspace ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=200,height=100 \
    ! mix.sink_4 \
```

Comment: Is it possible to create matrix 2x2 by using single `videosrc`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `framerate=5/1` from all your actual videos. For me, only `videotestsrc` can be modified with `framerate` capfilter.

```
gst-launch-0.10 -e videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink \
    uridecodebin uri=file:///home/user/Desktop/sintel_trailer-480p.webm ! \
            ffmpegcolorspace ! videoscale ! \
            video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=180 ! \
            videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=0 ! mix. \
    videotestsrc pattern=15 ! \
            video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=180 ! \
            videobox border-alpha=0 top=0 left=-320 ! mix. \
    videotestsrc pattern=13 ! \
            video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=180 ! \
            videobox border-alpha=0 top=-180 left=0 ! mix. \
    videotestsrc pattern=0 ! \
            video/x-raw-yuv, width=320, height=180 ! \
            videobox border-alpha=0 top=-180 left=-320 ! mix. \
    videotestsrc pattern=3 ! \
            video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=5/1, width=640, height=360 ! mix.
```